# Can I inspect any app's layout to find out which components they are using on Android device?

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, android-recyclerview, android-components

Can I take an app that I like and inspect it to see which components it is build off?

Take for example the menu structure of Androids "Developer Options" settings.
Say that I want to see if it uses one big `RecyclerView`, a `NestedScrollview` with a `RecyclerView` or a `RecycleView` with multiple nested `RecycleView's`.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is something like [VirtualUETool](https://github.com/zhangke3016/VirtualUETool). VirtualUETool can inspect other app's UI elements without their source code.

Comment: This work great!
I have no idea why this question got so much hate, but I really appreciate you taking it seriously. Thank you!